# Getting HandlerRegistration of @UiHandler

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I suppose the following code:

```
@UiHandler("button")
void click(ClickEvent event) {
   //do something
}
```

does something like

```
HandlerRegistration reg = button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

except it doesn't return HandlerRegistration object.

Is it possible to get HandlerRegistration object for the handler generated from UiBinder?

Is there any other way to remove such handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you need to manage the lifecycle of the handler, you have to `addClickHandler` yourself and keep a handle on the returned `HandlerRegistration`.